# Saving selected option from combo box to file using JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a problem, I'm not sure how to save selected option to a file.
What the code looks like is:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintWriter" %>
<%@ page import="java.time.LocalDateTime" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Combo box to file</title>
</head>
<body>
<%PrintWriter writer; %>
<select>
    <option value="Date">
        Current Date and Time
        <%
        writer = new PrintWriter("text.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        writer.close();
        %>
    </option>
    <option value="Text">
        Some Text
        <%
        writer = new PrintWriter("text.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Some text");
        writer.close();
        %>
    </option>
    <option value="Integer">
        An Integer
        <%
        writer = new PrintWriter("text.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(123);
        writer.close();
        %>
    </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

And it doesn't do anything. My guess is that the code isn't invoked but I'm very new to this, not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Try to avoid Scriplet instead use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Comment: did you try to write in the file after posting the data or just when the page is loaded ?

Comment: I want it to work after the page is loaded, I think this is the problem, still not sure how to fix that